# how to get all events from google calendar using google calendar API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

With reference of [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) I have made a application which gets information from google calendar event using google api. I have used the same code given in above URL.

Now there is one calendar with 2 calendar name like ME and XYZ. If I use my email Id then I only got the details of event with Calendar = "ME".
I have used below code

```
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = dtStart;
            request.TimeMax = dtEnd;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
            Events events = request.Execute();
```

How to get all the events details?

Comment: What's the problem here? Its very similar to the sample in the documentation so I think its already working. For more information regarding Events retrieval, you check out [its API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). You'll just need to to provide the `calendarId` for the Events of that calendar to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
>
> Returns events on the specified calendar.
>
> HTTP request
>
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events

As you can see from the documentation Events.list returns the events for A calendar.  If you have more then one calendar then you will need to request the events for that calendar as well.

Tip: You might want to look at

> [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) Returns entries on the user's calendar list.

This will return a list of the calendars the user has access to then you can loop though the events on each one of them.