# Make a HTTP GET to get all Meetings from Google Calendar

Tags: rest, curl, google-api, google-calendar-api

## Goal

to make an HTTP get to get all meetings based on the current day (today), Then I will make an HTTP PUT to update my Philips hue lights a few mins before the meeting to warn me.

## Steps

I've done these steps already and have the API_KEY noted.

1. Sign in to the Google Cloud console - https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Select your Google's project (or create a new one)
3. Search for the **Google Calendar API** and enable it
4. On the main menu, select "APIs & Services" then "Credentials
5. Create an API Key

I saw these:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

I wasn't sure if I am looking at the right calendar object

Am I looking at the right place ? Pls advise.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) to return events on the specified calendar. *Read the same SO scenario here:* [how to get all events from google calendar using google calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169118/how-to-get-all-events-from-google-calendar-using-google-calendar-api)

Alternatively, you can also retrieve an event using its `iCalendar ID`, call the events.list method using the `iCalUID` parameter. *You may read further details here:* [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get)

As for getting all the meetings based on current day, there isn't a way to get it directly, you can use the method `Events: list` then set the `timeMin` and `timeMax` from start of current date up to the last hour of the day. *You may read the same SO scenarios here :*

- [How to get today's events from Google Calendar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599217/how-to-get-todays-events-from-google-calendar-in-android)
- [How to get current events from google calendar API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981480/how-to-get-current-events-from-google-calendar-api)

For more information on Google Calendar API: [Develop Google Calendar solutions](https://developers.google.com/calendar?csw=1)